# Using grep command in makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm trying to use this command in (#!/bin/bash) makefile:

```
grep 'svseed' tc_1/tc1.log | awk '{print $7}'
```

If I use this command in my terminal its working fine. But if i use it in makefile its not printing the value of `$7`. I came to know that its searching for the `($7)` variable in makefile. I want that `($7)` variable to store in any other variable

How is not there in the makefile, how to solve this issue?

Is this possible or not?

Comment: You should probably switch to GNU Make, and avoid Posix Make. Posix Make is anemic and you can't do much with it. If you use GNU Make, then checkout [the shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html). For real world application see [this GNUmakefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile).

Comment: Why don't you use shell script for running specific functions? That looks to be much better suited for your purpose.

Comment: @jww thanks for the suggestion. sorry, i'm not using /bin/bash . i thought   the default script is bash that's why i mentioned it as #!/bin/bash

Comment: @AmeyaVS yes, i will tell you the whole thing what i want to do is with makefile i'm creating a file called tc1.log, in that file i have a line started with 'SVSEED' and in that line i'm printing the 7th word of that line using grep command

Comment: @jww i have not written #!/bin/bash in my makefile, i read it in somewhere they said, default script is bash and even in my system the default script is bash.

Comment: Add `SHELL = bash`. Now the shell will be bash for all recipes.  I use a Makefile-help to have things like this as well as auto documenting Makefile help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
grep 'svseed' tc_1/tc1.log | awk '{print $$7}'
```

To escape a dollar sign in a makefile, you have to double it.

Comment: now i want to append that $$7 to tc1.log file, likewise (tc1_3846875.log) normally that $$7 have a random value that value i want to append to my log file.. can you help me outfrom this